# Laravel - Redis caching on model level

Tags: laravel-5, redis

I came from *CodeIgniter* using *memcached*. 
Basically, a model call in CI was very different:

`$this->model_name->get_some_row_by_id($id);` 
which would return a row.

So caching would be done by having 
`get_some_row_by_id` look in the cache first, if no hit, then use the `callback` to fetch it from the database and store it.

I like this method of caching on the model level as any controller which needs to use the model will automatically use the cached call.

I've been reading all the documentation in *Laravel* and from what I can see, I cannot do this on the model level without some massive hacks, caching happens inside the controller using `Cache::remember`.

The biggest issue I see with this is the need to define cache in every controller and then keep track of the proper keys if I want to cache objects by `id->row` rather than by page composition.

If anyone has a method to accomplish something similar in Laravel to what I did in *CodeIgniter*, I would love to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache.

And the Retrieving Items From The Cache section says:

> You may even pass a Closure as the default value. The result of the Closure will be returned if the specified item does not exist in the cache. Passing a Closure allows you to defer the retrieval of default values from a database or other external service:

```
 $value = Cache::get('key', function () {
    return DB::table(...)->get();
 });
```

It is same like **"caching would be done by having  get_some_row_by_id look in the cache first, if no hit, then use the callback to fetch it from the database and store it"**. The code above only fetch it from db and not store it into cache , but you can add it.

And about cache configure of laravel

> By default, Laravel is configured to use the file cache driver, which stores the serialized, cached objects in the filesystem. For larger applications, it is recommended that you use a more robust driver such as Memcached or Redis.